# How to turn off location services?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

If a user has location services on, I assign my RootController as its delegate:

```
appDelegate.clLocationManager.delegate = self;
```

where appDelegate is an instance of my application delegate, which is where I have the location services instance. clLocationManager is an instance of CLLocationManager.  If I discover the user is outside of a certain region, I want to  disable location service delegates.  I do this:

```
appDelegate.clLocationManager.delegate = nil;
```

But this method still fires:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Is there another way to disable location services or at least keep its methods from firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to tell it to stop updating location:

```
[appDelegate.clLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

After that you can also release it.

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopUpdatingLocation) for details.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but didUpdateToLocation fires three more times after calling stopUpdatingLocation.  Shouldn't it stop updating immediately?

Comment: For it to work, I had to release and then immediately alloc the location manager.

Comment: @4thSpace would you mind providing code on how you fixed it? Honestly, I think that Apple screwed up big time with this. I can't get location services to stop at all, I've tried everything.

Comment: @4thSpace @Fulvio it's very weird I agree. I fixed it just by creating `BOOL locationManagerIsUpdating` and manually set it `TRUE` when I start updating, and `FALSE` when I stop. Then when I get updates I check the status of the Boolean.

Comment: I resolved this issue by calling stopUpdatingLocation and making delegate as nil.